# Google Cloud: Where to add a task to the Cloud Tasks queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am stuck here:
https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quickstart?hl=ca-ES#add_a_task_to_the_cloud_tasks_queue

Where to put and export the environment variables (PROJECT_ID, LOCATION_ID and QUEUE_ID), because the documentation says I should put them in the code in my sample app but I don't know in which file exactly. I am using NodeJS

```
export PROJECT_ID=PROJECT_ID // The project ID from above
export LOCATION_ID=LOCATION_ID // The region in which your queue is running
export QUEUE_ID=my-queue // The queue you created above
```

Comment: What do you want to do? The env vars are simply passed in parameter of the script `createTask.js` that you can find here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/blob/master/samples/createTask.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll simply need to set the [environment variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) depending on your OS.

The [export](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/export.1p.html) command is meant to be run in a Terminal if using in UNIX bases systems (Linux, MacOS).

If you are using Windows you'll need to make a few more clicks.

The following [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) goes through all the details for all major OSes.